# Unit testing Java application with Mockito/JUnit-Database operations

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am just beginner for implementing JUnit testing. I have a test case as given below. I have tried the when...thenreturn + verify method as well.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CategoryControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    CategoryController categeoryCntrlr;
    @Mock
    private CategoryService catSvc;
    //private CategoryController catCntrl;

    @Test
    public void insertCategoryTest(){
        Category cat=new Category();
        cat.setStrCatName("Vehicle");
        String str = categeoryCntrlr.insertCategory(cat);
        System.out.println(str);
        assertEquals("failure",str);
    }
}
```

My Controller returns actually string 'success' but my above test case always says value of str as null.

When I used when...thenreturn() and verify, it is not actually testing my repository method, even if I change the return to something else the test case is passing. I know there is behavioral and testing. Is there any solution we can have both together? Can I get some beginners tutorial(I saw the calculator example and find methods tested, but no insert/update database)? I am not able to understand the reference document of Mockito, how it actually testing. Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your goals are for `insertCategoryTest()`, but you probably want to stub methods in your controller and/or service.

For example, to stub the `insertCategory()` method in your controller to always return `"failure"`, you'd do the following:

```
when(categeoryCntrlr.insertCategory(any())).thenReturn("failure");
```

There are more examples about verifying interactions and stubbing method calls here: http://mockito.org

Link to Javadoc:

http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html

Comment: I am doing testing my controller, with mocking the service and the jparepository. I want to test it inserts and return success. I tested the above with 'failure' and it got pass. The testing happens whatever I give in thenReturn it is testing against it, not the actual implementation.

Comment: It does not matter what actual method returns, it matter what is in when..thenReturn method.

Comment: I might be having wrong understanding. But that is what I am getting for my testing.

Comment: The goal of mock objects is to make it easier and faster to test your business logic.  It replaces components in your system, e.g. a database server, or an external REST API, that make it difficult and/or slow to test.

Comment: Can you step through `categeoryCntrlr.insertCategory(cat);` with a debugger and determine why it's returning `null`?

Comment: It would help if you could provide the source code for the components you are trying to test.